# Перегрузка оператора "+="

Tags: c++

уважаемые форумчане. Подскажите пожалуйста ищущему путь новичку.
Пытаюсь выполнить перегрузку += с помощью метода класса.
Создал класс Point

```
{
private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
public:
    Point();
    Point(int x, int y);
    friend Point operator += (Point& obj1, Point& obj2);
    friend Point operator += (Point& obj1, int x);  
};
```

Реализацию его методов

```
Point::Point()
{
    m_x = 0;
    m_y = 0;
}
Point::Point(int x, int y)
{
    this->m_x = x;
    this->m_y = y;
}
Point operator += (Point& obj1, Point &obj2)
{
    int tmp_x = obj1.m_x+obj2.m_x;
    int tmp_y = obj1.m_y + obj2.m_y;
    return Point(tmp_x, tmp_y);
}
Point operator += (Point &obj1, int x)
{
    int tmp_x = obj1.m_x + x;
    int tmp_y = obj1.m_y + x;
    return Point(tmp_x, tmp_y);
}
```

Для проверки выполняю

```
Point pt1(1,1);
        Point pt2(2,2);
        pt2+=pt1;
        pt2+=1;
        Point pt3(3,3);
        pt2 += pt1 += pt3;
        stop
```

И вот в этой строке возникает ошибка - E0349    отсутствует оператор "+=", соответствующий этим операндам(типы операндов Point += Point):

```
        pt2 += pt1 += pt3;
```

Учитывая, что += бинарная правоассоциативная операция.
Предположил, что возвращается новый объект, в следствие чего не происходит дальнейшая перегрузка
Пробовал внутри класса реализовать при помощи возврата *this, однако это так же не помогло.
Подскажите пожалуйста куда меня заводит криворукость?
Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: Оператор не может быть перегружен с помощью метода. И что за суперхитрость в присваивание пихать локальные переменные да ещё и возвращать их? Присваивание может возвращать только ссылку на this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто. Вы требуете в качестве аргумента `Point&`, т.е. lvalue, а возвращаете? `Point operator +=`.

Для решения проблемы **в вашем варианте** оператора `+=` лучше всего заменить аргументы на `const Point&`.

Но подумайте — что обычно делается в выражении `a += b`? К `a` прибавляется `b`, и `a` получает новое значение. `a = a + b`. У вас же `a` остается неизменным...

Так что если бы вы хотели получить оператор *с верной семантикой*, то меняли бы объект, переданный в качестве первого аргумента, и возвращали бы ссылку на него.

Comment: Спасибо большушее, очень помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете перегрузку оператора сложения, которая возвращает новый объект, а не изменяет текущий. Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, вам необходимо изменить реализацию перегрузки, чтобы она изменяла текущий объект:

```
Point &operator += (Point& obj1, Point &obj2)
{
    obj1.m_x += obj2.m_x;
    obj1.m_y += obj2.m_y;
    return obj1;
}
Point &operator += (Point &obj1, int x)
{
    obj1.m_x += x;
    obj1.m_y += x;
    return obj1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большушее, очень помогло.